# IsTabStop = False on a SL4 Text box

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, tabstop

I set IsTabStop to false on a text box and I know that this makes the control unable to receive focus, but according to the [Silverlight Forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/33523/103597.aspx), it should still be able to receive mouse events. I have the MouseLeftButtonUp event wired and a breakpoint in my tbxTotal_MouseLeftButtonUp method, and it never gets hit during debugging. The thread in the SL Forums is pretty old now, so maybe this was changed in an update somewhere. I want a text box that can't be tabbed to, but is still editable. Should it really be this hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize this, but it seems to be the case, Additionally, I can't seem to get MouseLeftButtonUp to fire.  MouseLeftButtonDown does fire though and using that you can do this hack.

```
<TextBox IsTabStop="False" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

Then in code you can handle the event like this.

```
    private void TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = ((TextBox) sender);
        textBox.IsTabStop = true;
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.IsTabStop = false;
    }
```

It might be worth while to wrap it in a CustomControl

```
public class FocusableTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsTabStop)
        {
            IsTabStop = true;
            Focus();
            IsTabStop = false;
        }

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, didn't even see if MouseLeftButtonDown worked. Just goes to show assuming is bad. Thanks.

Comment: But annoyingly, just calling .Focus on MouseLeftButtonDown doesn't work that why you have to play the on/off dance :(

Comment: Also, because my text box is in a tree view, some weird things are happening. When I click my text box, the mouse down gets fired, I set IsTabStop to true, give it focus, and in LostFocus, I set IsTabStop to false. However, the tree view item that the text box is in gets focus, thus cancelling what I just did out. The tree view item has IsTabStop set to false, so I find it odd that it can receive focus, but I hacked around that too. In my text box LostFocus event, I actually give focus to my text box again, then directly after, set IsTabStop to false.

Answer (score 1):

@seekerOfKnowledge: Disabling `IsTabStop` on the `LostFocus` is a good approach, but your re-focus hack is unnecessary.  It fails to have any visible effect the first time around because the change of `IsTabStop` has not yet taken effect.  This approach can be also be taken with any other control.

```
        var control = sender as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) =>
                {   //This event fires even if the control isn't allowed focus. 
                    //As long as the control is visible, it's typically hit-testable.
                    if (!control.IsTabStop)
                    {
                        control.IsTabStop = true;
                        //threading required so IsTabStop change can take effect before assigning focus
                        control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                control.Focus();
                            });
                    }
                };

            control.LostFocus += (sender, args) =>
                {   //Remove IsTabStop once the user exits the control
                    control.IsTabStop = false;
                };
        }
```